# iPhone No volume control shows up on specific phone when using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

We've written an app that uses the MPMoviePlayerController to play movies streamed from a server. It works fine on a bunch of devices we own (2 iPads, 3 iPhones) and a few others at our customer site but for one particular Japanese fellow, he gets no sound and no volume control?

Any suggestions?

PS I did ask him to reboot his phone and he has the vibrate switch off

Answer (score 0):

ok it does pay to ask silly questions a second time. He did have vibrate switch on. Now the question is why YouTube app doesn't remove the volume controls when that happens and our app does but I just need to research that now.